# Store SMS template in database and render it later

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to store SMS template in database. Something like `Hello, {{ $userName }}`.

Apparently it'd be a good solution to use blade templates here. However how can I retrieve sms template from database and compile it with some variables? The same way I do it with views when rendering blade templates but instead render it from database?

Comment: How about use blade templates contain content `Hello, {{ $userName }}`, db just save real name, `rome, etc` :|

Comment: Unfortunately Blade compiler interface does not have that option, it only accept a path to a view `public function compile($path);` but I believe it can be extended

Comment: checkout this [package](https://packagist.org/packages/wpb/string-blade-compiler). It renders the blade template stored as a string.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to create a temp view file everytime you want to send SMS with your template

```
$templateFromDatabase = 'Hi, {{$username}}';

$tempFilePath = time().'.blade.php';
File::put($tempFilePath, $templateFromDatabase);

//Render your view
$html = View::make($tempFilePath,['username'=>'My Name']);
```

Comment: Well, imagine I need to send sms to 1000 users, I'll need to create temp file 1000 times...?

Comment: No, you don't need to create 1000 file, just create one like this
<br/>
$tempFilePath = $lastUpdateOfTemplateInDatabase.'.blade.php';
<br/>
And you should check the time stamp of last update before generate the file

Comment: Oh, you mean for each template stored in DB make a separate file?

Comment: Yes, if you have several template

Answer (score 0):

Search for delatbabel/viewpages on github. Supports storing templates in the database, either blade or twig format.